# removing undefined values from the key

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data set in the form of:

```
string0 string1 string2 string3
<int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
<int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
<int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
<int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
```

Normally, I plot this as a histogram where string0 is my xtic using the code below.

```
47 plot mydata using 6:xtic(int($0)%5==0?stringcolumn(1):"") title column(6), \
48   mydata using 5 title column(5), \
49   mydata using 4 title column(4), \
50   mydata using 3 title column(3), \
51   mydata using 2 title column(2)
```

The problem I have is that in my data-set, it's normal to have 0 values for some columns, but those columns are still printed and end up in the *key*.

Is there a way to ignore them? I tried something similar to this.

```
47 plot mydata using (6 == 0 ? NaN : 6) :xtic(int($0)%5==0?stringcolumn(1):"") \
   title column(6), \
48   mydata using (5 == 0 ? NaN : 5) title column(5), \
```

However; that completely throws off the key. 
 
[image: Example]

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know ahead of time which columns will be blank?  If so you can use the `notitle` flag to the plot command.

Comment: I create the data on my own through perl scripts, hmm I think that may work. I was hoping not to have to change my data generation.